# Add helper text to payment method form

Tags: 7, commerce

I would like to add helper texts to the different options in the payment methods form, in Drupal Commerce, like this:

**/Radio button/ Payment method 1**

Helper text option 1...

**/Radio button/ Payment method 2**

Helper text option 2....

This is what one of the payment method options looks like in code:

```
/**
* Implements hook_commerce_payment_method_info().
*/
function swish_payments_commerce_payment_method_info() {
  $payment_method = array();

  $payment_method['payment_method_1'] = array(
    'base' => 'payment_method_1',
    'weight' => 20,
    'title' => t('Payed for with mobile pay'),
    'display_title' => t('Pay with mobile pay'),
    'description' => t('Choose this option if.....'),
    'active' => TRUE,
    'offsite' => FALSE,
    'offsite_autoredirect' => FALSE,
  );

  return $payment_method;
}
```

The content of the description field doesn't show anywhere in the specific payment method (in the Settings pane at the bottom of the page admin/commerce/config/payment-methods/manage/xx).

So how can I add helper texts to the options under each payment method in the form?

Comment: The table of  *Store->Config->Payment methods * build by this `commerce_payment_ui_admin_page` function they didn't add description to markup take a look at this http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/commerce/modules--payment--includes--commerce_payment_ui.admin.inc/function/commerce_payment_ui_admin_page/7

Comment: So you can override the page callback here http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/commerce/modules--payment--commerce_payment_ui.module/function/commerce_payment_ui_menu/7 and add it yourself in custom module .

Comment: It turns out I wrote the wrong path in my question. The payment method title can be seen under Settings on the bottom of the page admin/commerce/config/payment-methods/manage/xx, but not the description.